# [New to git]git push origin master created new master branch. (default-main in repo)

Tags: git, github

```
git push origin master
```

So I tried git push origin master and it has created a new branch master. Turns out, my main branch is main while the past repos that i tried had master as main branch. How do I solve this? How can I merge these branches or make master my default branch?

Comment: Related but a bit different: [How do I update my GitHub mirror due to the master/main change?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64618081/1256452)

Comment: Closely related, maybe still not a duplicate: [My Github repo has 'main' and 'master' branches - what is their purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65020647/1256452)

Comment: Very closely related: [How to merge main and master branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65369949/1256452)

Comment: Not to mention https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename a branch, use the command:
`git branch -M [NAME_BRANCH]`
so in your case:
`git branch -M master`
as soon as you have renamed the branch 'master', you can continue as if nothing had happened

Answer (score -1):

git branch -M master

use the upper command to rename your master branch

Comment: This is what the previous answer from last year already proposes.